# "edit" not a valid command in cmd.exe?

Tags: windows, cmd, editor

I'm trying to create a .cfg file for bcc32 compiler and I'm following the instructions. I have installed correctly and placed an environment path as instructed but when I type "edit bcc32.cfg" into the command prompt it says that edit isn't a valid command? What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Which operation system?

Comment: cmd.exe implies Windows... probably 7 or 8.

Comment: The "edit" command is missing from all 64-bit versions of Windows because it is a 16-bit application. 64-bit Windows has no 16-bit subsystem and so cannot run such programs.

Answer (score 10):

You could also create a .bat file, **edit.bat**, to replace the 16-bit edit program (removed because x64 windows flavors won't run it) which would launch your favorite editor.

```
@echo off
notepad %1
@echo on
```

This is what I wound up doing as a simple patch so I could carry on the way I always had for the most part. Just type:

```
edit myfile.ext
```

in the command prompt to use it.

Note: notepad is not my favorite editor - this is just an example that will work with stock windows.

Note 2: @echo off and @echo on are shown for clarity.  You may also shorten this by omitting the echo statements and simply placing the @ before the command to be silenced.

```
@notepad %1
```

Comment: Because is Windows, calling notepad would actually work and is a valid answer.

Answer (score 4):

I just use notepad (since they took out the edit command) from the command window like so:

```
 C:\Borland\BCC55\bin> notepad bcc32.cfg
```

The file will open in notepad for editing. When you've finished editing the file, save it and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

I have found this works for seeing in-window text of a complete file, on a 64bit machine. Once your path is set in cmd prompt, type the word type... followed by "filename" do you see how I used the quotes around the filename only!

```
type "filename"
```

You type it just like this (changing filename for your files name) and you will be able to see the entire file text in the cmd window. Not sure how to edit from here on but maybe someone can figure it out from here and tell me.

Comment: It's works well, and is very useful to see text files content while working on different encodings.

Comment: This answer does not address the question about `edit`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Windows 7 (where `edit.exe` and `edlin.exe` have been removed):
Use `powershell.exe` instead of `cmd` - thereby `edit` will be available via command line.

Take a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell

Comment: thanks for your replies, i'm using windows 8 does this make a difference?

Comment: also I tried powershell in windows 8 and it still says edit is not a valid command. All i'm trying to do is use Borland c compiler to compile a little program I made for and assignment.

Comment: okay so you're running the 64 bit version. several command line tools have been removed in 64 bit (under win 7 too). you might want to install `vim` (command line tool under unix). you can find the 64bit version for windows here:
https://code.google.com/p/vim-win3264/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help i'll try installing that

Comment: you're welcome. did it solved your issue? if yes please accept the answer to mark it as solved for other users with the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

simple answer.... 
if your using an old version of windows (xp e.t.c...) you would be able to use edit
but since your using new version of windows, Microsoft has updated and removed the commands that they think are not relevant e.g.. (msg, edit) depending if its a bit32 bit64 or bit82...